# Integrating Fiddle Code Into Layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

With the help of a Stack Overflow user named Michael, I was able to get this jsFiddle division to drop down properly. However, when I try to implement the JavaScript, CSS, and HTML, even into a new directory with only the jsFiddle code, I can't get the divisions to drop down on click.  It won't show the content division at all, actually. What am I doing wrong?

I'm guessing that I've got to be implementing the JavaScript code wrong somehow.

The jsFiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/WeL6j/12/,

```
$(function() {
    $('.action').click(function() {
        var content = $(this).find('~ .content');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').not(content).hide('fast');
        content.slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Without actually seeing the code that doesn't work, it's unlikely that anybody can simply guess your mistake.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library? `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, I figured that much.  I'll post a simple pastebin with the basic files and includes.  And yeah, I included the jquery file for it.

Comment: What is the issue? So far you've said you had trouble getting the fiddle to work. however I opened up your link and it seems to work well for me.

Comment: html - http://pastebin.com/sGzsG7bT
css - http://pastebin.com/dF20LEpP
javascript (jquery 1.7.1) - http://pastebin.com/deQ5MrnV

Comment: Well, the fiddle works just fine, but whenever I try to recreate the effect outside of fiddle in notepad, I can't get it to work.  I'm exhausted and I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, but I can't figure it out.  Thanks in advance for the help, Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jQuery ***before*** you use it... a good way to ensure this is to put the `<script>` tag that includes jQuery **before** you code. Or you can move your code to the bottom of the body just before `</body>` [read more](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/24-javascript-best-practices-for-beginners/)

```
<head>
<title></title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="container"><ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="action">summer</a>
        <div class="content">
            <a href="link">june</a>
            <a href="link">july</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="action">winter</a>
        <div class="content">
            <a href="link">november</a>
            <a href="link">december</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="action">weather</a>
        <div class="content">
            <a href="link">rain</a>
            <a href="link">sun</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    </ul></div><br>
<div id="div">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//$(function() { // ooo looky, i'm not actually needed now!
    $('.action').click(function() {
        var content = $(this).find('~ .content');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').not(content).hide('fast');
        content.slideToggle('fast');
    });
//});?
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I should really stay off stackoverflow this early in the morning.  I appreciate it.